# winbuilder does not find packages in devel version that it finds in release version

Tags: r

I am preparing an R package to be uploaded to CRAN. I have already checked using rhub and every check passed. I have also checked using winbuilder for the release version of R (devtools:check_win_release) and there were no ERRORs or WARNINGs. However, for the devel version (devtools:check_win_devel) I got the following error:

```
checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Packages required but not available:
  'tidyr', 'googlesheets', 'stringr', 'readtext'

Package suggested but not available for checking: 'knitr'

VignetteBuilder package required for checking but not installed: 'knitr'

See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.
```

I would really appreciate some help to figure out what's going on. This is the relevant part of my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Imports:
    XML (>= 3.98),
    purrr (>= 0.2.4),
    dplyr (>= 0.7.8),
    tibble (>= 2.0.0),
    tidyr (>= 0.7.2),
    rlang (>= 0.3.0.1),
    googlesheets (>= 0.3.0),
    stringr (>= 1.4.0),
    readxl (>= 1.3.1),
    readtext (>= 0.7.1),
    zip (>= 2.0.4),
    xml2 (>= 1.2.0),
    rjson (>= 0.2.20),
    shiny (>= 1.3.2),
    tools (>= 3.5.3),
    utils (>= 3.5.3),
    R.utils (>= 2.9.0)
Suggests:
    knitr (>= 1.9),
    rmarkdown (>= 1.12),
    testthat
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Comment: This is a problem on Winbuilder, which they're working on:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2019q4/004701.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It is very good to know the source of the issue :)